# After incrementing data, Discord message sent to user is off by 1

Tags: python, pymongo, discord.py

When I increment the win by 1 in the DB, and return the amount of wins the user has, it is always off by 1.

For example in the code below:

```py
import discord
import pymongo

client = discord.Client()
mongo = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = mongo.collection
profiles = db.profiles

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

if message.content.startswith('!iwin'):
    profile = profiles.find_one({'discordID': message.author.id})
    updatewin = profiles.find_one_and_update({'discordID': message.author.id}, {"$inc":
                                                                 {"wins": 1, "coins": 40}})
    win_msg = "Your win has been recorded. You have {} wins!".format(profile['wins'])
```

If I type !iwin, the 1 win gets recorded in the DB, however the message that gets returned is `Your win has been recorded. You have 0 wins!`
And if I type !iwin again, the second win gets recorded, for a total of 2 wins, but the message reads `Your win has been recorded. You have 1 wins!`
It seems to me like the message gets sent prior to the increment happening, how do I get around this?

**EDIT**
It also affects any type of operation I try to add using the wins field. For example:

```py
win_msg = "Your win has been recorded."
await message.channel.send(win_msg)
if profile['wins']%2==0:
    roll = random.randint(1,809)
    roll_msg = "You have won 2 games! Here is your roll: {}. Would you like to !keep or !reroll?".format(roll)
    await message.channel.send(roll_msg)
```

It always calculates it wrong. So if I have 2 wins in the DB, it doesn't give the roll, but if I have 1 win in the DB, it *does* calculate the roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just explicitly add 1 within your string formatting. It would look like:

```
win_msg = "Your win has been recorded. You have {} wins!".format(int(profile['wins']) + 1)
```

You probably don't need the `int()` either, but I usually throw it on so it is clear to both the computer and my future self what my intent was.

From your update it would seem maybe your database actually isn't being updated the way you expect. I'm not sure what your `find_one()` method returns, but it may be a static value (probably would be a good idea to include in your post). Have you tried verifying it with print statements like this? (Also, I think your `if` block is supposed to be indented?)

```
if message.content.startswith('!iwin'):
    profile = profiles.find_one({'discordID': message.author.id})
    print(profile)
    updatewin = profiles.find_one_and_update({'discordID': message.author.id}, {"$inc":{"wins": 1, "coins": 40}})
    print(profile) # has this changed?
    # maybe you need to call your find_one method again? Like
    profile = profiles.find_one({'discordID': message.author.id})
    print(profile) # is it updated now??
```

Comment: That definitely seems like a nice and easy solution, but I feel like there's an underlying problem that would impact any calculations done on the wins. I have updated my question with an edit. And thank you for the very fast response.

Comment: @aishaq11 I think for more help you would need to include your `find_one()` code

Comment: `find_one()` is a pymongo function which allows you to query for a document and store it as a dict.

Comment: @aishaq11 Well including the code would be best, but it sounds like the dictionary it returns is static and not linked to the document it was originally made from (checking for updates).

Comment: The `import pymongo` statement is about as far as it goes. [Docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)

Comment: @aishaq11 have you tried the print statements though? I would think after fetching the updated dictionary from the updated document it would work, no?

Comment: Holy smokes i figured it out! I have to state my `profile` variable after my `updatewin` variable. `profile` was getting read in first, before `updatewin`, which meant it was always behind the increment.
Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @aishaq11 Glad to help :) `print()` statements are surprisingly useful!